# Is there an accepted definition for the median of a sample on the plane, or higher ordered spaces?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, spatial, median

If so, what?
If not, why not?

For a sample on the line, the median minimizes the total absolute deviation. It would seem natural to extend the definition to R2, etc., but I've never seen it. But then, I've been out in left field for a long time.

Comment: [K-medians, formula to compute the geometric median](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89676/k-medians-formula-to-compute-the-median/271441#271441)

Answer (score 25):

I'm not sure there is one accepted definition for a multivariate median.  The one I'm familiar with is [Oja's median point](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/Geometric-Estimators/oja.html), which minimizes the sum of volumes of simplices formed over subsets of points.  (See the link for a technical definition.)

Update: The site referenced for the Oja definition above also has a nice paper covering a number of definitions of a multivariate median:

- [Geometric Measures of Data Depth](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/Papers/depth.pdf)

Comment: Nice reference: thanks.  It comprehensively covers everything mentioned here.

Comment: The same website also contains a nive overview in html: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/Geometric-Estimators/intro.html

Answer (score 19):

As **@Ars** said there are no accepted definition (and this is a good point). There are general alternatives families of ways to generalize quantiles on $\mathbb{R}^d$, I think the most significant are:

- [**Generalize quantile process**](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-20/issue-2/Generalized-Quantile-Processes/10.1214/aos/1176348670.full) Let $P_n(A)$ be the empirical measure (=the proportion of observations in $A$). Then, with $\mathbb{A}$ a well chosen subset of the Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\lambda$ a real valued measure,
  you can define the empirical quantile function:

$U_n(t)=\inf (\lambda(A) : P_n(A)\geq t A\in\mathbb{A})$

Suppose you can find one $A_{t}$ that gives you the minimum. Then the set (or an element of the set) $A_{1/2-\epsilon}\cap A_{1/2+\epsilon}$ gives you the median when $\epsilon$ is made small enough. The definition of the median is recovered when using $\mathbb{A}=(]-\infty,x] x\in\mathbb{R})$  and $\lambda(]-\infty,x])=x$. **Ars** answer falls into that framework I guess...  **tukey's half space location** may be obtained using $\mathbb{A}(a)=( H_{x}=(t\in \mathbb{R}^d :\; \langle a, t \rangle \leq x ) $ and  $\lambda(H_{x})=x$  (with $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $a\in\mathbb{R}^d$).

- [**variational definition and M-estimation**](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-25/issue-2/M-estimation-convexity-and-quantiles/10.1214/aos/1031833659.full)
  The idea here is that the  $\alpha$-quantile $Q_{\alpha}$ of a random variable $Y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ can be defined through a variational equality.
- The most common definition is using the **quantile regression function**   $\rho_{\alpha}$ (also known as pinball loss, guess why ? )  $Q_{\alpha}=arg\inf_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\mathbb{E}[\rho_{\alpha}(Y-x)]$. The case $\alpha=1/2$ gives $\rho_{1/2}(y)=|y|$ and you can generalize that to higher dimension using $l^1$ distances as done in **@Srikant Answer**. This is theoretical median but gives you empirical median if you replace expectation by empirical expectation (mean).
- But [Kolshinskii](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-25/issue-2/M-estimation-convexity-and-quantiles/10.1214/aos/1031833659.full) proposes to use  Legendre-Fenchel transform: since $Q_{\alpha}=Arg\sup_s (s\alpha-f(s))$
  where $f(s)=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E} [|s-Y|-|Y|+s]$ for $s\in \mathbb{R}$.
  He gives a lot of deep reasons for that (see the paper ;)). Generalizing this to higher dimensions require working with a vectorial $\alpha$ and replacing $s\alpha$ by $\langle s,\alpha\rangle$ but you can take $\alpha=(1/2,\dots,1/2)$.
- [**Partial ordering**](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=55:26) You can generalize the definition of quantiles in $\mathbb{R}^d$ as soon as you can create a partial order (with equivalence classes).

Obviously there are bridges between the different formulations. They are not all obvious...

Comment: Nice answer, Robin!

Answer (score 14):

There are distinct ways to generalize the concept of median to higher dimensions.  One not yet mentioned, but which was proposed long ago, is to construct a convex hull, peel it away, and iterate for as long as you can: what's left in the last hull is a set of points that are all candidates to be "medians."

["Head-banging"](http://surveillance.cancer.gov/headbang) is another more recent attempt (c. 1980) to construct a robust center to a 2D point cloud.  (The link is to documentation and software available at the US National Cancer Institute.)

The principal reason why there are multiple distinct generalizations and no one obvious solution is that the real line $\mathbb R^1$ can be ordered but $\mathbb R^2, \mathbb R^3,\ldots$ cannot be.

Comment: Any measure that coincides with the usual median when restricted to R1 is a candidate generalization. There must be a lot of them.

Comment: phv:> one can ask for 'the' generalization to preserve (in higher dimensions) some of the interesting properties of the median. This severly limits the number of candidates (see the commenting after Srikant's answer below)

Comment: @Whuber:> then notion of ordering can be generalized to R^n for unimodal distributions (see my answer below).

Comment: @kwak: could you elaborate a little?  The usual mathematical definition of an ordering of a space is independent of any kind of probability distribution, so you must implicitly have some additional assumptions in mind.

Comment: @Whuber:> You state: "R1 can be ordered but R2, R3, ... cannot be". R2,..,R3 can be ordered in many ways by mapping from Rn to R . One such way is the tukey depth. It has many important properties (robustness to some extend, non parametric, invariance,...) but these only hold for the case of unimodal distributions. Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: @Kwak: A continuous mapping from R^n to R cannot induce a total order.  Technically, I was wrong, because any bijection from R^n to R will "order" R^n via the order on R, but this order will not be compatible with any of the metric structure on R^n (which is an essential part of the concept of a "median"), and that was the spirit of my comment.

Answer (score 14):

[Geometric median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) is the point with the smallest average euclidian distance from the samples

Comment: Also [Why is the geometric median called the L1
estimator?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113239/why-is-the-geometric-median-called-the-l-1-estimator),   [K-medians, formula to compute the median](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89676/k-medians-formula-to-compute-the-median)

Answer (score 7):

A definition that comes close to it, for unimodal distributions, is the tukey halfspace median

- [resource 1](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/%7Eathens/Geometric-Estimators/halfspace.html)
- [resource 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20110708190243/http://www.isical.ac.in/%7Estatmath/html/publication/Tukey_tech_rep.pdf)
- [resource 3](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Estatmath/report/11310-15.pdf) $^\dagger$

---

$\dagger$ not active

Comment: Could you check the third link? Apparently it is not loading and it was not archived.

Answer (score 6):

The Tukey halfspace median can be extended to >2 dimensions using DEEPLOC, an algorithm due to Struyf and Rousseeuw; see [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.2052) for details.

The algorithm is used to approximate the point of greatest depth efficiently; naive methods which attempt to determine this exactly usually run afoul of (the computational version of) "the curse of dimensionality", where the runtime required to calculate a statistic grows exponentially with the number of dimensions of the space.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if any such definition exists but I will try and extend the [standard definition of the median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#An_optimality_property) to $R^2$. I will use the following notation:

$X$, $Y$: the random variables associated with the two dimensions.

$m_x$, $m_y$: the corresponding medians.

$f(x,y)$: the joint pdf for our random variables

To extend the definition of the median to $R^2$, we choose $m_x$ and $m_y$ to minimize the following:

$E(|(x,y) - (m_x,m_y)|$

The problem now is that we need a definition for what we mean by:

$|(x,y) - (m_x,m_y)|$

The above is in a sense a distance metric and several possible candidate definitions are possible.

**[Eucliedan Metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_metric)**

$|(x,y) - (m_x,m_y)| = \sqrt{(x-m_x)^2 + (y-m_y)^2}$

Computing the median under the euclidean metric will require computing the expectation of the above with respect to the joint density $f(x,y)$.

**[Taxicab Metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)**

$|(x,y) - (m_x,m_y)| = |x-m_x| + |y-m_y|$

Computing the median in the case of the taxicab metric involves computing the median of $X$ and $Y$ separately as the metric is separable in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Srikant:> No. The definition has to have two important feature of the univariate median. a) Invariant to monotone transformation of the data, b) robust to contamination by outliers. None of the extentions you propose have these. The Tukey depth has these qualities.

Comment: @kwak What you say makes sense.

Comment: @Srikant:> Check the R&S paper cited by Gary Campbell above ;). Best,

Comment: @kwak On thinking some more, the taxicab metric does have the features you mentioned as it basically reduces to univariate medians. no?

Comment: @Sri:> no. For instance: if you pre-multiply $x,y$ by a non singular,symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, the ranking of the $|(x_i,y_i)-(m_x,m_y)|$ will change. The taxicab metric is not affine invariant. The median is invariant to a even larger group of transformation (it is monotone invariant). Same for robustness, an arbitrary small contamination of your dataset by an observation $x_i$ located at $+\infty$ will cause the location of $m_x$ to shift without bounds, hence changing, again, all the rankings of the $|(x_i,y_i)-(m_x,m_y)|$. The taxicab metric has a breakdown point of $0$.

Comment: The median, again, has a break down point of 50 percent (the bivariate tukey depth has a break down point of 33 percent (1/(1+p)) and is monotone invariant.

Comment: @kwak I see the point. I will not delete this incorrect answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: @Srikant:> there are no incorrect answer to phv's questions because there are no 'good answers' either; this area of research is still under development. I simply wanted to point out why it is still an open problem.