# Median zero in the multivariate case

Tags: probability, multivariate-analysis, quantiles, median, random-vector

I have a question about the definition of the median of a (continuous) random vector $X\equiv (X_1,..., X_r)$. As suggested [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Multivariate_median)  and by other discussions in this forum (e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43009/what-are-the-multidimensional-versions-of-median) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/is-there-an-accepted-definition-for-the-median-of-a-sample-on-the-plane-or-high)) there are various definitions of median for the multivariate case.

Suppose that
$$
(A) \quad \Pr(X_1\geq 0,..., X_r\geq 0)=\Pr(X_1\leq 0,..., X_r\leq  0)=0.2
$$

Is there any uncontroversial relation between (A) and the notion of "median equal to zero", independently of the definition of multivariate median one could use?

Comment: There is no reason to believe (A) implies the "marginal median" is $0$ and similarly with the other multivariate medians.